# OPENCV training cascade "out of range"

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to train my own detector by using OpenCV 3.0 traincascade.
I have 82 positive and 188 negative sample and with the following

```
 opencv_traincascade -data data -vec signals.vec -bg negative.txt -numPos 82 -numNeg 188 -numStages 20 -w 50 -h 50 -featureType LBP
```

I'm able to reach stage 8. At the stage 9 I have the following error

```
    ===== TRAINING 9-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   82 : 82
NEG cterminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
Aborted (core dumped)149
```

Someone knows why? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is - you don't have enough negative samples for selected `maxFalseAlarm` and `numStages` parameters. So you have 3 options (starting from the best):

- provide more negative samples (imho it's the best option - it's not hard and will give you the best results)
- decrease value of `maxFalseAlarm` parameter (you can find it [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html#cascade-training))
- decrease number of stages

If i remember correct (better check it..) you should have at least `(1-maxFalseAlarm)^(numStages-1)` (where '^' is power, not xor) negative samples to complete training.

Comment: I was thinking about the number of negative and now you confirm my thoughts. Thank you!